# selecting only children through JQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('div','#ele').each(function() {
   someArray.push($(this)); 
});
```

pushes all descendants divs into the array. How do I limit this to only children divs of #ele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('#ele > div').each(...);
```

Or, since you use the context argument in your jQuery call, if you pass the context as a variable, you can use [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead:

```
// $ele is a jQuery object
$ele.children('div').each(...);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. context tip appreciated